# Moving/Migrate a VM to Hyper-V Server 2012 R2

Tags: virtual-machines, migration, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Ok what am I doing wrong?

Picture the scene.  One test network with 3 devices on it.

- 1 x Windows 2012 Server R2 (Domain Controller)
- 1 x Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit (Member of the domain)
- 1 x Hyper V server (Member of the domain)

Note the HyperV server is in fact “Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2” which is ISO from the Eval Section with unlimited expiry (Is that right, unlimited and free, is that to compete against VMWare ESXi).

It isn’t a Windows 2012 Server install with HyperV feature enabled, it’s a pure Hyper-V Server.  More information here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833684(v=ws.11).aspx)

I have created a VirtualMachine on the Windows10 PC using the Hyper-V tools from Windows 10.

I now want to deploy that VM to the Hyper-V server.  But how??

There doesn’t seem to be a way to access the local drives on the Hyper-V server except from the hyper-v server itself.
When you try and map a drive that works, but I get permission denied messages.
So I gave the server (computer object) access rights on the share and folder, but still permission denied.

I can export the VM from Win10, but can't see a way to import on the Hyper-V server.

It would also appear I can’t “migrate” from the Win10 to Hyper-V.

I can however move my VM from Win10 to the Win2012 server (also running hyper-v) and then move from there to the hyper-v server but that does seem a long way of doing it.

Please, what am I doing wrong…

I was hoping to create and test a VM locally on a Win10 PC and then deploy (migrate) direct to the Hyper-V server.

## # # # # # ## Additional Comment added to Question## # # # # #

Below added to answer the posts of ToddW and JakeO

Hmmm

This is disappointing.  I was hoping the same was possible for Hyper-V as it was for VMWare.  I.e. Create your VM on a Windows10 PC using VMWare Workstation, then using VMWare Converter, convert the VM and upload to an ESXI server.

I was hoping that I could do the same the with Hyper-V.  Create the VM on Windows10 and migrate to Hyper-V Server (bare metal) and not migrate to Hyper-V feature running on a Windows 2012 R2 server.

JakeO, To answer your question about the importing….

I tried to import from the Hyper-V server.  I did this by doing the following.

On my Windows10 PC I ran the Hyper-V manager, connected to the Hyper-V server and select import VM.
File Manager window pops up at the local C: drive of the Hyper-V server.

So I gave “the computer” object of the Hyper-V Full Access to my PC and then in the file manager window tried to navigate to my PC and get Permission Denied.  Tried various ways to give the server access to my PC and even the Server2012 but just permission denied.

So I thought I’d try the other way round.  Logged in as a Domain Admin, I would try and navigate to the C Drive on the Hyper-V server by going to \HyperVSrvr\C$ but nope.  It would appear the Hyper-V bare metal server doesn’t have file sharing on.

ToddW, in your post you say I need to give the user object access rights and not the server object.  However Hyper-V Server (installed into the domain was just a computer object added) there was no special user objects created.  On the Hyper-V server which runs sconfig at boot time I added the server (option 1) to the domain and Added a local admin (option 3) same details as the domain admin.

In the end I gave up….

All I was trying to do was develop a VM locally on a Windows10 PC and then deploy it to a Hyper-V Server.  Of course I could deploy to the Hyper-V on the Windows 2012 R2 server and then migrate to the Hyper-V server, but I don’t see why I need a Windows 2012 R2 server as a staging server.

Sadly my searching for usual links on the Internet comes up short, because most articles talk about Hyper-V running as a feature on Windows2012 server and not just the bare metal version.

Comment: When you are interactively logged on to one computer and you attempt to access a resource over the network on another computer, it's the **user** account that requires access to the resource, not a computer account. "So I gave the server (computer object) access rights on the share and folder..." that's your problem (or at least one of your problems). You have to authorize the user in question to access the share and folder, or grant permission to the Everyone object.

Comment: Todd, thanks for your reply, I've added comments to my original question as there wasn't enough space in a "comment" to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is essentially the same version of Windows that is found in Windows Server 2016.  Server 2012R2 is the same version as Windows 8.1  So, to move a virtual machine from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1 (Server 2012R2) you need to first create the machine with a down-level version, using PowerShell or WMI.  The Hyper-V Manager will always create a current-level VM.

But you have an existing VM that won't run on Server 2012R2.  You have a couple of choices.

1)  You could replace your Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 with the prerelease Hyper-V Server 2016, and then it would be able to import your VM after you export it.

2)  You could create a new VM, downlevel, on the client machine and then export it.

But since both of those options have big drawbacks...

3)  You should copy the VHDX file from the client machine and make a new VM on your Hyper-V Server, using the copy of the VHDX.  It will be a new VM, of the right level.  And it will do what you want.

Lastly, it's not clear from your message when you said you couldn't see a way to import it, whether you meant that the versions didn't match and the import failed, or that you failed to discover the import mechanism.  Hyper-V Server is meant to be managed remotely, probably through scripts.  You can either connect remotely to it using Hyper-V Manager, or you can just use PowerShell to do everything you want:

PS> enter-pssession nameofhypervserver

[nameofhypervserver] PS> new-vm

(or)

[nameofhypervserver] PS> import-vm

Comment: Jake, thanks for your reply, I've added comments to my original question as there wasn't enough space in a "comment" to answer you.